# Django/JavaScript: generating HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

world. I'm still newbie in Python and JavaScript, so my code and my methods may look a bit 'strange' for experienced developers, but let's hope I will learn a thing or two today.

I've got a HTML page where some code was generated by django:

Django function generating html table code:

```
def calendar_days_define(cMonth, cYear):
    Calendar = []
    calendarMatrix = calendar.monthcalendar(cYear, cMonth)
        for element in calendarMatrix:
            Calendar.append('<tr>')
            weekday = 0
            for i in element:
                weekday += 1 
                    if weekday > 5:
                        if i > 0:
                            Calendar.append('<td class="days_Weekends_days">{0}</td>'.format(i))
                        else:
                            Calendar.append('<td class="days_Weekends_days"></td>')
                    else:
                        if i > 0:
                            Calendar.append('<td class="days_Works_days">{0}</td>'.format(i))
                        else:
                            Calendar.append('<td class="days_Works_days"></td>')
            Calendar.append('</tr>')
        DoneCalendar = ''.join(Calendar)
        DoneCalendar = '<table id="calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh">{0}</table>'.format(DoneCalendar)
        return DoneCalendar
```

It generates nice calendar wrapped in HTML table, exactly how i need it.
The problem arise when I want to generate a new table for different month. I need to generate new calendar table, so i use ajax call by JavaScript to get django generate me a new HTML table code and then replace the old table with the new one:

```
function redrawCalendar(cMonth, cYear) {
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/edit/ajax_change_calendar',
  data: {cMonth: cMonth, cYear: cYear},
  success: function (data) {
   $('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh').replaceWith(data);
  }
 })
}
```

This get me a nice new table but the problem is that I cannot access this new table. For example:

```
$('.days_Work_days').css("color","red")
```

no longer works. Why?
I get a feeling that more appropriate method is to generate code for table by JavaScript on client side, if this is the case I will rewrite it, but still the question bothers me. If anyone can help me here I'd greatly appreciate it, thanks.

UPDATE

Here is the part of my initial HTML page where changes occur:

```
<table><tr><td> {{ defineCalendar|safe }} </td></tr></table>
```

When page loads django populate this variable with calendar table with id="calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh" and source page then looks like

```
<table><tr><td> 
 <table id="calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh"> ...a bunch of <tr> and <td> with days numbers as value... </table>
</td></tr></table>
```

I can access this table in JS as $('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh'). For example:

```
$('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh').css('border-collapse','collapse')
```

Everything's fine.
When I want to generate a new calendar table without reloading the whole page I call ajax JS function which I showed previously. After that HTML part looks like that:

```
<table><tr><td> 
 <table id="calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh"> ...a bunch of <tr> and <td> with different days numbers as value... </table>
</td></tr></table>
```

Looks pretty much the same, but when I do again for example:

```
$('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh').css('border-collapse','collapse')
```

nothings happens.

The JS happens when I click a button:

```
$('#calendarBtn_Back').click(function() {
    redrawCalendar(cMonth, cYear)
)}
```

The button is outside calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh table, but inside the table which contains it.

FINAL UPDATE

Ok, that was pretty dumb on my part. It took me 2 days for god sake.
My mistake was that I didn't showed you guys exactly what I was doing. I said I was using

```
$('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh').css('border-collapse','collapse')
```

when in reality it looked like this:

```
var calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh = $('#calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh');
```

and then this global variable was used in some function as:

```
calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh.css('border-collapse','collapse');
```

When the page loads everything works fine. But when I dynamically replace the table with a new one even with the same id, the bind with the variable apparently breaks. When I moved variable declaration inside the function so the variable binds to element every time when function called the problem solved.
Well, thanks to everybody for replies. Your advices got me thinking in right direction. Next time I'll make sure to post exact and accurate snippets.

Comment: Seriously, you should use a template to generate HTML, that's what they're for.

Comment: yes, i strongly recommend to read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/

Comment: And you'll need to give more details about the problem. Where are you using that JS that doesn't work? What does the HTML look like after you've done the replacement?

Comment: All that is fine. Could it be that the JS itself - or whatever is triggering it - has been replaced by the Ajax call? That's why I asked where that `css()` is being called from. Is it perhaps triggered by an onclick on a button which is inside `calendar_Inside_Changeable_Mesh`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several possibilities i can think of, you should eliminate them one by one:

- Bad html
- Script dealing with css never got called after replacing the html
- CSS selector wrong or xpath of target DOM element got changed

Make use of debug console and paste more information if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this line is not working is becuase you have spelt the class name wrong.

```
$('.days_Work_days').css("color","red")
```

Within the python code you are looking for `days_Works_day`

```
if i > 0:
    Calendar.append('<td class="days_Works_days">{0}</td>'.format(i))
else:
    Calendar.append('<td class="days_Works_days"></td>')
```

Change your js to be:

```
$('.days_Works_days').css("color","red")
```

Comment: Unfortunate that's not the case, because I type this css line here manually just to show that I can't address the element. But I found my mistake, I put an update in topic post.